# HTTPS : Sending client certificate in javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, cordova, https

I have a client certificate which i am planning to use in a HTML5 mobile app for user authentication. Is it possible to select client certificate and send a HTTPS Ajax call using phonegap or any frameworks.

Thanks